# Use Jsch with InputStream is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsch

I'm trying to send a file using JSCH over SFTP protocol.

Here is the `FileService` file

```
public class FileService {

    public void send(){
        String str = "this is a test";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            var channel = setupJsch();
            channel.put(is, "test.txt");
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private ChannelSftp setupJsch() throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession("foo", "localhost", 2222);
        jschSession.setPassword("pass");
        jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jschSession.connect();
        return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    }
}
```

But the `JSch` is throwing a `NullPointException` with this message:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide()" because "this.io_in" is null`

I already tried with `OutputStream` and the result is the same.

Could you help me?

[Update 1]

After trying the @Ogod suggestion

```
    public void send(){
        String str = "this is a test";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            var channel = setupJsch();
            channel.start();
            channel.put(is, "test.txt");
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It has thrown the following message `java.io.IOException: channel is broken`

Comment: @user207421 The original error was the `NullPointerException`. In a comment (which is deleted now - why?) I suggested to try `channel.start()` before `channel.put(...)`. Because this suggestion was not completly right, the next error was the `IOException`.

Comment: `channel.start()` was just a step in the right direction but this method shouldn't be called externally. The right method is `channel.connect()` which is written down in my answer. Anyway the block [Update 1] in the question should be removed because it is confusing without the comments which aren't available anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are just missing the call to `channel.connect()` right before executing `channel.put(...)`. This will setup the `channel` so that the internal variable `io_in` is assigned to an `InputStream` (this fixes the `NullPointerException`).

Additionally you should properly close the `channel` if you don't need it anymore by calling `channel.disconnect()` or `channel.exit()`. This will ensure that all resources are released.

```
public class FileService {

    public void send(){
        String str = "this is a test";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            var channel = setupJsch();
            channel.connect();   // this should do the trick
            channel.put(is, "test.txt");
            channel.exit();      // don't forget this
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private ChannelSftp setupJsch() throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession("foo", "localhost", 2222);
        jschSession.setPassword("pass");
        jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jschSession.connect();
        return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained, in words and not just code, what the problem was, and how you addressed it.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the hint, I have added an explanation to my answer that hopefully clarifies a bit what was the source of the error.

Comment: You should probably also do `jschSession.disconnect()`, in addition to `channel.disconnect()`.